# mutable array in 1 class in 2 button actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I generate some immutable arrays through 1 IBAction but when I reference them from another IBAction within the same class  I can not retrieve the answers.  Partial code I have for the creation in the 1st action is:

all arrays are init within this 1st `IBAction`.  Here is a sample of the vType:

```
NSMutableArray *vType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Gather components for Value Calculations  

//NSLog(@" myInv count(h) = %lu and catDetail count(g) = %lu", (unsigned long)[myInv count], (unsigned long)[catDetail count]);

for (h = 0; h < [myInv count]; h++){

    //NSLog(@"vScott objectAtIndex:h = %@ AT %d", [vScott objectAtIndex:h], h);

    for (g = 0; g < [catDetail count]; g++){

        //NSLog(@"cvScott objectAtIndex:g = %@ AT %d", [cvScott objectAtIndex:g], g);

        //NSLog(@"vScott objectAtIndex:h = %@ AT %d", [vScott objectAtIndex:h], h);

        if ([[vScott objectAtIndex:h] isEqualToString:[cvScott objectAtIndex:g]]){

            [vSerStart insertObject:[cvSerStart objectAtIndex:g] atIndex:h];
            [vType insertObject:[cvType objectAtIndex:g] atIndex:h];
            [vUnitCost insertObject:[cvFacePrice objectAtIndex:g] atIndex:h];
            [vYear insertObject:[cvYear objectAtIndex:g] atIndex:h];

            //NSLog(@"vScott (vIndex) / cvScott (cvIndex) = %@ (%d) / %@ (%d)", [vScott objectAtIndex:h], h,[cvScott objectAtIndex:g],g);
            //NSLog(@"cvSerStart Object %@ atIndex:p = %d",[cvSerStart objectAtIndex:g], g);
            //NSLog(@"cvType Object %@ atIndex:p = %d",[cvType objectAtIndex:g], g);
            //NSLog(@"vScott / vSerStart / vType // AT (myInv) Index p =  %@ / %@ / %@ // %d", [vScott objectAtIndex:h],[vSerStart objectAtIndex:h], [vType objectAtIndex:h],h);
            //NSLog(@"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");


            //NSLog(@" The value calculation Scott Numbers are:%@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@ * %@",[vScott objectAtIndex:h], [vExt objectAtIndex:h], [vSer objectAtIndex:h], [vNew objectAtIndex:h], [vUsed objectAtIndex:h], [vPlate objectAtIndex:h], [vSht objectAtIndex:h], [vSerPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vNewPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vUsedPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vPBPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vShtPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vSerStart objectAtIndex:h],[vType objectAtIndex:h]);

            vOutLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", [vScott objectAtIndex:h], [vYear objectAtIndex:h], [vExt objectAtIndex:h], [vType objectAtIndex:h], [vSer objectAtIndex:h],[vNew objectAtIndex:h], [vUsed objectAtIndex:h], [vPlate objectAtIndex:h], [vSht objectAtIndex:h], [vUnitCost objectAtIndex:h], [vSerPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vNewPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vUsedPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vPBPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vShtPrice objectAtIndex:h], [vSerStart objectAtIndex:h]];

    //NSLog(@"vOutLine = %@", vOutLine);
    NSLog(@"%@",[vType objectAtIndex:h]);

    [valueData addObject:vOutLine];
```

Results for the Mutable Array (vType) are:

```
2014-10-24 23:00:53.233 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] C
2014-10-24 23:00:53.233 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] C
2014-10-24 23:00:53.233 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] C
2014-10-24 23:00:53.233 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] C
```

---

Trying to use the values stored in a 2nd Action within the same class I was using this code to test:

```
- (IBAction)btnValueCollectionDataTable:(id)sender {

    int k,l,m,n;
    NSMutableArray *vType;

    //if ([[vScott objectAtIndex:h] isEqualToString:[cvScott objectAtIndex:g]]

    for (k = 0; k < [myInv count]; k++){

        NSLog(@"%@",[vType objectAtIndex:k]);
        //if ([[vType objectAtIndex:k] isEqualToString:@"C"]){

           //convert required elements to Integer


           //calculate required elements

    //}else{

    }
}
```

The results of this trial for the vType array are:

```
2014-10-24 23:01:00.634 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] (null)
2014-10-24 23:01:00.634 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] (null)
2014-10-24 23:01:00.634 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] (null)
2014-10-24 23:01:00.634 Stamp Collection[6313:1331161] (null)
```

I thought once initialized within the class an array would be available anywhere.  I would appreciate advice as I am stuck here.

Comment: To build up on Zaph's answer you need to declare @property NSMutableArray in your class, either in the .h or in the interface section of the .m. That is [Objective-c encapsulation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply the `NSMutableArrays` are declared local to each method. If you want to access the same `NSMutableArray` from more than one method make it a property of the class (or an instance variable).

You need to read-up on the basics of variable scope.

Comment: Good question, not really easy to answer. Here is one for beginning developers (we all are once): [Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Objective-C-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/032194206X/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414260117&sr=1-2&keywords=big+nerd+ranch)

Answer (score 1):

vType array is local to first IBAction. Hence its scope is limited to first action only.
If you want to access the vType array in second IBAction as well, declare it as a property in interface.

```
@property(nonatomaic,strong) NSMutableArray * vTypeArray;
```

And in first and second IBAction access this property.

Comment: Thank you both for this reply.  I am learning as I work on this project. Help from experienced people is invaluable.  Would i allocate and initialize in the 'awake from nib' to accomplish this.

Comment: If you are sure when it will be first used, you can initialise on first access,otherwise viewDidLoad is good place to intialise. It's a good practise to accept the answer if it solves the problem :) All the best

Comment: I have the above line in .m interface, have initialized array in the 1st action. Can you give me a line example for 'access'.  I have tried 'instance.' but I am sill not getting data in each action.

Comment: IN viewDidLoad allocate as follows self.vTypeArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];and in first and second action access using [self.vTypeArray addObject:] and [self.vTypeArray objectAtindex:]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this and study the results to help me learn.  You are too kind.